# embed video stream with custom meta data

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have an optical system that provides a UDP video stream.

From device specification FAQ:

> Both single metadata (KLV) stream and compressed video (H.264) with metadata (KLV) are available on Ethernet link. Compressed video and metadata are coupled in the same stream compliant with STANAG 4609 standard. Each encoded video stream is encapsulated with the associated metadata within an MPEG-TS single program stream over Ethernet UDP/IP/ The video and metadata are synchronized through the use of timestamps.

Also there are other devices that provide data about the state of an aircraft (velocity, coords, etc). This data should be displayed on a client GUI display alongside with video. Of course it has to be synchronized with the current video frame.

One of the approaches I though of is to embed this data into the video stream. But I am not sure if it is possible or should I use another (than UDP) protocol for this purpose.

Is it possible/reasonable to use such approach? Is ffmpeg library suitable in this case?
If not, what are the other ways to synchronize data with a video frame.
Latency is crucial. Although bandwidth is limited to 2-5 Mbps.

---

It seems to be possible using ffmpeg: `AVPacket` can be provided with additional data using function `av_packet_add_side_data` which takes a preallocated buffer, size and a type `AVPacketSideDataType`.
However, I am not sure for now, which [enum value](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__packet.html#ga9a80bfcacc586b483a973272800edb97) of `AVPacketSideDataType` can be used for custom user-provided binary data.

Something similar that might be used for my needs:

[How do I encode KLV packets to an H.264 video using libav*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140590/how-do-i-encode-klv-packets-to-an-h-264-video-using-libav)

Comment: Is the data supposed to be part of the video or separate?

Comment: @llogan I think it is supposed to be contained within the video stream as a way to synchronize it with the corresponding video frame.

Comment: If you want it in the actual video image, such as "burned-in" like hardsubs, you can use the drawtext filter with the `reload` option. But maybe you want it as separate data?

Comment: @llogan I don't want it to be drawn on the actual frame. I need it a separate data. Is there a way to add it to video stream as some kind of meta data?

Comment: What's the container?

Comment: @Gyan I've updated the question. The container is MPEG-TS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quote sounds like you have a transport stream containing two elementary streams (the H.264 video in one, and the KLV data in another). The transport stream is sent over UDP (or TCP, or is just a file, whatever you want - its mostly independent of the transport).

There is a discussion of implementing this kind of thing in the Motion Imagery handbook (which you can download from the MISB part of the NSG Registry at https://nsgreg.nga.mil/misb.jsp - its towards the bottom of the Non-cited Standards Documents table) and in detail in ST 1402 (which you can find in the same table). I'm avoiding providing direct links because the versions change - just look for whatever is current.

The short version is that you can embed the timestamp in the video (see ST 0603 and ST 0604), and then correlate that to the metadata timestamp (Precision Time Stamp, see ST 0601). You don't want to do that at the `AVPacket` level though. Instead, you need to put side data into `AVFrame`, with the `AV_FRAME_DATA_SEI_UNREGISTERED` key (https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#ggae01fa7e427274293aacdf2adc17076bca4f2dcaee18e5ffed8ff4ab1cc3b326aa). You will need a fairly recent FFmpeg version.

Note: if all you want to do is see the UDP data stream - video on one side, and decoded KLV on the other, then you might like to check out the jMISB Viewer application: https://github.com/WestRidgeSystems/jmisb
It also provides an example of encoding (generator example). Disclaimer: I contribute to the project.

Comment: The nga.mil links don't work any more. I found a list at [nga registries](https://nsgreg.nga.mil/registries/browse/results.jsp?registryType=doc&registerField=any&itemTypeField=doc&filterField=name1&showField=m&statusField=valid&dayField=14&monthField=5&yearField=2022&tzOffset=240&sortField=name1asc&nsgKeywordField=all&stdstatusField=all&disrServiceAreaField=all)

Comment: @mheyman - good point. Have updated the question with a slightly different link that should be fairly stable and give you just the MISB parts.